# Invalid username or password WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I need your help, when I try to type in login and username and click log in button the website returnes a "wrong username or passord" even if it is correct and in console it always loops, what should I do? I was thinking about somehow allow follow links?

Here is WebPage.java (the webview actitity)

```
public class WebPage extends AppCompatActivity {
static WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Username");
    final String pwd = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Password");
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    String url = "http://www.webnotes.cz/";
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('UID0').value = '" +user+ "';document.getElementById('PASS0').value='" +pwd+ "';javascript:document.getElementById('butLogon').click();");
        }
    });
    SystemClock.sleep(1500);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy%20hh:mm:ss");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.webnotes.cz/Distrib_v.asp?ET='"+date+"'");
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
}
public boolean onCreateWindow (WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg) {

    ((WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj).setWebView(mWebView);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
    return true;
}
```

Here is console code:

```
W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 26296
W/WebKit: ResourceFetcher::requestResource, type = 0, policy = 3, url = https://www.webnotes.cz/Distrib_v.asp?ET=10.11.2016%2019:13:27
W/chromium: [WARNING:registry_controlled_domain.cc(356)] getTopDomain, host = webnotes.cz, topDomain = .cz
W/chromium: [WARNING:registry_controlled_domain.cc(356)] getTopDomain, host = webnotes.cz, topDomain = .cz
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=www.webnotes.cz; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=2
D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: www.webnotes.cz get result from proxy >>
D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f91e28400,w=1080,h=1920)
D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:13(114:155); file:external/openssl/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:145;Function:ASN1_get_object
```

[Log in screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PMVi.jpg)

thanks for your answers

Comment: Does `view.loadUrl("[some javascript]");` work?

Comment: You cannot perform time consuming actions such as loading a web page in the main thread. You have to do it in the background with `AsyncTask`. Google for it.

Comment: Yes the `view.loadUrl("[some javascript]");` does work